# How to fire an iron-signal from outside of Polymer Element in Polymer 1.0?

Tags: polymer-1.0

I have a normal javascript file app.js that does book-keeping for the application that I am building. Is it possible to fire an [iron-signal](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-signals) event from app.js. Please note that app.js is not a Polymer element.

Answer (score 3):

Found a way to do it:

`var event = new CustomEvent('iron-signal', {'detail' : {name: 'foo', data: 'null'}});
document.dispatchEvent(event);`